# There is no any response from save button

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, cascadingdropdown

I will be thanks for your kind help and support in my case as the save button of my registration forum it doesn't work i click many times on it but nothing happen it suppose to save records in database and move me to another page but nothing happen at all.

```
    public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    string sc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeravaConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable countrycascd = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeravaConnectionString"].ConnectionString))


            {
                SqlDataAdapter adaptar = new SqlDataAdapter("select [countryID],[country] FROM [countr]", con);
                adaptar.Fill(countrycascd);

                countrdrdolst.DataSource = countrycascd;
                countrdrdolst.DataTextField = "country";
                countrdrdolst.DataValueField = "countryID";
                countrdrdolst.DataBind();
            }

            countrdrdolst.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("select country", "0"));
        }
    }


    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sc);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        string sqlstatment = "INSERT INTO UserInfo (UID, FN, LN, Password, RePass, Email,Country, State,City, Post, Img) VALUES (@UID,@FN,@LN,@Password,@RePass,@Email,@Country,@State,@City,@Post,@Img)";

        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = sqlstatment;

        //Insert the parameters first
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", UsrNme.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", fnbox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", lnamebox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", passtxtbx1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RePass", passtxtbx2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", emailbox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", countrdrdolst.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", statedrdolst.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", citiesdrdolst.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Post", postbox.Text);

        //Check if there's a file or not
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile && FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/users/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", FileUpload1.FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            //Must add the paramater value to any value or DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", "");
        }

        //Open the connection and execute the command
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //Close the connection
        cn.Close();
        Response.Redirect("User panel.aspx");


    }




    protected void countrdrdolst_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int countryID = Convert.ToInt32(countrdrdolst.SelectedValue);
        DataTable StateDT = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeravaConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adaptar = new SqlDataAdapter("Select [StateID],[State] FROM [State] WHERE [countryID] = " + countryID, con2);

            adaptar.Fill(StateDT);

            statedrdolst.DataSource = StateDT;
            statedrdolst.DataTextField = "State";
            statedrdolst.DataValueField = "StateID";
            statedrdolst.DataBind();
        }

        statedrdolst.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("select State", "0"));


    }

    protected void statedrdolst_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int StateID = Convert.ToInt32(statedrdolst.SelectedValue);
        DataTable City = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con3 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeravaConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adaptar = new SqlDataAdapter("select [CityID],[City] FROM [Cities] WHERE [StateID] = " + StateID, con3);
            adaptar.Fill(City);

            citiesdrdolst.DataSource = City;
            citiesdrdolst.DataTextField = "City";
            citiesdrdolst.DataValueField = "CityID";
            citiesdrdolst.DataBind();
        }

        citiesdrdolst.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("select City", "0"));
    }

    protected void citiesdrdolst_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


}
}










<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SVM.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Registration.aspx.cs" Inherits="beravoSV.Registration" %>
```

```
<style type="text/css">
.style5
{
    width: 191px;
    color:#606060;
}
    .style6
    {
        float: left;
        height: 25px;
        color: White;
        font-size: small;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 9px;
        background-color: #a340bf;
    }
</style>
```

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>


<div class="banner728">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl="~/images/general/bann72890.png" />
</div>
<div class="space">
</div>
<div class="style6">
    <strong style="font-size: medium">Registre New User</strong></div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<table style="width: 69%; height: 338px;" align="center">


   <tr>

   <td class="style5"> &nbsp; Användarnamn</td>
    <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="UsrNme" runat="server" Width="258px" Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
   <td>
       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Userreqlbl" runat="server" 
           ControlToValidate="UsrNme" ErrorMessage="This field is required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
       <br />
       </td>


   </tr>


    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Förnamn
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="fnbox" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="258px" 
                ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Efternamn
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="lnamebox" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="258px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Lösenord
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="passtxtbx1" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="258px" Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="passtxtbx1"
                ErrorMessage="This part is required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Återskrivnings Lösenord
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="passtxtbx2" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="258px" Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="passtxtbx1"
                ControlToValidate="passtxtbx2" ErrorMessage="The password is not match" ForeColor="Red"></asp:CompareValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; E-post
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="emailbox" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="258px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="emailbox"
                ErrorMessage="Invalid Format" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Land
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="countrdrdolst" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                onselectedindexchanged="countrdrdolst_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Län
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="statedrdolst" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                onselectedindexchanged="statedrdolst_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Stad
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style11">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="citiesdrdolst" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                onselectedindexchanged="citiesdrdolst_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style12">
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Postnummer
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="postbox" runat="server" Width="258px" CausesValidation="True" 
                Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp; Personlig bild
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left" class="style8">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>


   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp;
            </td>
        <td class="style8">

            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Create" onclick="btnSave_Click" />



        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
<br />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Can you please paste your `page.aspx` code of `Button` which you want to be clicked?

Comment: You get any exception or error message?

Comment: Try cutting down your code to a minimal test case that demonstrates the problem. We need the code for the button, the callback for the button, any error messages and any details you get by attaching a debugger / use the browser developer tools

Comment: Does your page postback on button click or just nothing?

Comment: Thanks guys for your quick response please find out the update i add already my page.aspx code

Comment: put your btnSave button (in .aspx page) outside of update panel and check !!

Comment: It seems like your Button click event is working fine. Only that `Response.Redirect()` part is not working. Thats why you see no change in your page. Recheck the URL of that Redirected page.

Comment: Hardik Vinzava: I have double check but its same.

Comment: Chandan Roy: nothing happen i tried as you said :-(

Comment: @Simo : Give a try :- comment all your code written in btnSave_Click event and just put Alert there to check out its calling or not or its error from Response.Redirect("User panel.aspx"); .

Comment: @Hardik Vinzava this button will make me crazy nothing happen still as it is no any response i follow what you told me but same

Comment: @Simo than put your code somewhere and allow me to check it all

Comment: Hi All 

Sorry to bother you but finally its work the problem was from java script in the master page i just remove it and its work fine now thank all of you :-))))